# How to send a loop on several nodes with Slurm?

Tags: r, loops, nodes, slurm

I have a R script that I would like to execute on several nodes. I show the loop of my slurm code :

Edit

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o job-%A_task.out
#SBATCH --job-name=paral_cor
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=124G                #I want to use 124Go / node
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=32        #and 32CPUs / node 
#SBATCH --exclude=hpcsmp01


module load gcc/8.1.0 openblas/0.3.3 R

OUTPUT="$HOME"/PROJET_M2/data/$(date +"%Y%m%d")_parallel_nodes_test
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"

export FILENAME=~/PROJET_M2/bin/RHO_COR.R

echo "Start job :"`date`

for i in $(seq 100)
do
   srun Rscript my_scrit.R --subset $i  
done

echo "Stop job :"`date`
```

I execute this basically

```
sbatch my_script.sh
```

This is the loop in my R code where `--subset $i` appears:

```
res <- foreach(i = opt$subset) %dopar% {      #without argument, that gives
 G1 <- split[[combs[i,1]]]                    i=seq_len(nrow(combs))
 G2 <- split[[combs[i,2]]]                    combs is a vector with several
 dat.i <- cbind(data[,G1], data[,G2])         rows, according to my input 
 rho.i <- cor_rho(dat.i)                      file
}
```

I want to execute the different value of `i` on several nodes. This code is only executed on one node. Do you have an issue to run this code on several nodes?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the full SLURM script? How are you sending this to queues?

Comment: Do you also want I show you the loop of my R code where the argument `subset` appears?

Answer (score 1):

In your current state, you are asking SLURM for a single node, a single task and 32 cores for that task. If you want to use more than one node, you should tell SLURM:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=10
```

Later, in the actual script start, you should tell `srun` to start that script in a single node:

```
srun --nodes 1 --exclusive Rscript my_scrit.R --subset $i &
```

You need to put the script in the background if you want to start the next iteration while the first one is still running. You also need the `--exclusive` flag to avoid starting an extra script on already allocated resources.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean. I was wondering if I create an external bash loop, which executes my script.sh could be a solution? I mean, I set one node with 32CPUs and 124Go in my script.sh , and there will be as much as executed jobs than there are iterations in the loop?

Comment: Yes, that could also be a solution, as long as you manage to give each submission the proper subset parameter. If you go that way, I advise you to use job arrays, they will simplify your task at hand.

Comment: I tried to use job arrays but it doesn't work correctly on the cluster. Could you help me to give each submission the propr subset paramater. This parameter should take values from 1 to X (X is the number which can change according to my input file in my code R). I don't really know how to create that..

Comment: You can create a submit script with the proper parameter for each of the jobs you want to start. This would be the manual approach to the job array, sending all of them separately.

Comment: I understand what you mean. My problem is just that I don't know how can I make the link between my argument `--subset $i` in my  slurm code , and how to increment this argument, thanks to the loop : `for i in ? ; do sbatch slurm_code.sh $i ; done` ?

Comment: I'm telling you not to have `--subset $i` in your SLURM code, but `--subset 1`, `--subset 2`... in the several files that you will create. At the end you will have several files (`slurm_code.1.sh`, `slurm_code.2.sh`...) that will have to be sent to SLURM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193818/discussion-between-paillou-and-poshi).